# Error in setting up goldbolt with childprocess launch failure

Tags: c++, godbolt

I got error in setting godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/MYcqjeMKe

```
Program returned: 255
[F][2022-02-14T15:04:35+0000][1] bool subproc::runChild(nsjconf_t*, int, int, int, int)():448 Launching child process failed
```

I observed that `<No output file /tmp/compiler-explorer-compiler2022114-6738-38ipku.u1md1/build/output.s>` is present, can you please help ?

Comment: You might want report the issue here https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues. SO is not a support for 3rd party online tools.

Comment: @273K do you have any idea what should i change to avoid this issue ? anything I try to do I face it.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this bug
https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/3649

and got the answer to simply change the output.s target to match the executable specified in the CMakeLists.txt.

This seems to work, although on the first project I tried this on I could not find a way to change output.s to something else.